# Conflicting Variables in pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am using the pusher pod and the starscream pod. When I try to use the class/type `Websocket` to open a socket using starscream, it causes issues because it conflicts with something in pusher. I get the error "Cannot invoke `WebSocket` with an argument list of type `(url: URL)`." As soon as I get rid of pusher, everything works perfectly. Is there any solution to this? Or do we have to install the pods manually and go in and change the variable/class names?

For your reference:
Here is the pusher pod: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift
Here is the starscream pod: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

Comment: Pusher appears to bundle the contents of Starscream in this file: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift/blob/master/Sources/Starscream.swift

Does it work if you remove your own dependency on Starscream?

Comment: I missed that! But even when I get rid of my own dependency, I am not able to use Starscream in my own project. I am getting errors that says `use of undeclared type 'websocket'` and when I try to import starscream, it says `No such module 'Starscream'`